# How to diff just the source files?

Tags: c, diff

I have two almost similar source code trees, but do not have access to the source code repository so I am stuck with release packages that contain also test reports, documentation, binaries etc.

the `diff` command only support `--exclude`, but I would like to do something like `diff -wbur --include='*.c,*.h' tree1 tree2`

I know that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483849/how-do-you-use-the-diff-command-against-two-source-trees) is somewhat related, but does not really address my issue.

Bonus points for ignoring change blocks that are completely in C comments :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Little modification to a result from google helped, in `tree1` did  `find . -name '*.[ch]' -exec diff -wibu {} ../tree2/{} \;`

Comment: For C++ source trees, try `-name '*.h" -o -name "*.cpp"` in the above command.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little patch maker script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USAGE="USAGE: $0 <dist dir> <edited dir>"

[ '--help' == "$1" ] && { echo $USAGE; exit 0; }
[ 2 -eq $# ] || { echo $USAGE; exit 1; }

# trim starting './' and trailing /'/
original=$(echo $1 | sed 's-^\./--;s-/$--')
changed=$(echo $2 | sed 's-^\./--;s-/$--')

[ -d $original ] || { echo "ERROR: Directory $original does not exist" >&2 ; exit 2; }
[ -d $changed ] || { echo "ERROR: Directory $changed does not exist" >&2; exit 3; }

#command="ls -l"
command="diff -Naur"

find $original -name '*.[ch]' -o -name '*.cpp' | sed 's-^[^/]*/--' | { while read file; do $command  $original/$file $changed/$file; done; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would exclude everything that doesn't match .c or .h. So it means it will only include .c and .h files :

```
diff -x "*.[^ch]"
```

For me it is the best way to do because you are only using diff

Comment: This does not work correctly: it includes extensions like .cpp, .hxx, .cache, and .help .

Answer (score 2):

You can write all files to exclude into a temporary file and give it to diff's `-X` argument.

```
find tree1 tree2 -type f -not -name '*.[ch]' >exludes
diff -wbur tree1 tree2 -X excludes
```

Or simplier (works in Bash):

```
diff -wbur tree1 tree2 -X <(find tree1 tree2 -type f -not -name '*.[ch]')
```

You can use multiple name arguments if you have longer filename extensions:

```
diff -wbur tree1 tree2 \
  -X <(find tree1 tree2 -type f -not -name '*.java' -and -not -name '*.sql')
```

Answer (score 0):

I proposed an easier solution than find to diff maintainers, here is the thread:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-diffutils/2014-10/msg00000.html

The idea is provide a new option which instructs diff to parse on files that match a regex, like:
`diff -Nurp --only "*.[hc]" source/ source-new/`

Here is the instructions to patch diffutils

Clone the repo
`git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/diffutils.git`

run `bootstrap.sh` inside diffutils directory and resolve the dependencies until it creates the ./cofigure script

Download the patch from link above

Apply it
`git apply <PATCHFILE>`

Configure and compile
`./configure`
`make`

This will create the patched diff in src/diff

Cheers

Comment: I've added the patch that solves my problem. Now seems to be a good answer for me :)